# Is it possible to use a DNS server as a proxy?

Tags: internal-dns, hacking, isp, dns-server

My mobile internet provider cuts my internet service at times before it was due, I contacted them and they did nothing about it
I noticed I could still ping hostnames, thus I can connect to the dns server, can I somehow proxy my traffic through the dns server or trick my provider into thinking i'm only using the dns while i'm using the internet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There methods of surfing the web when regular TCP traffic is not allowed, but DNS traffic is. One popular piece of software is [iodine](https://code.kryo.se/iodine/).

You would need control over a real domain, though.